# ADFS 3.0 OAuth Token Refresh (Windows Server 2012r2)

Tags: oauth, adfs

We've setup ADFS 3.0 (Windows Server 2012R2) in combination with Work Folders (as described here http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2014/03/03/deploying-work-folders-with-ad-fs-and-web-application-proxy-wap.aspx)

Everything works: domain and non-domain joined computers can connect to the workfolder and the sync works.

However, the OAUTH refresh token does not work. Hence the credentials must be re-entered after the initial token is expired.

The event log displays the following information:

> Source AD FS Event ID: 1021 Encountered error during OAuth token
>   request.
>
> Additional Data  Exception details: 
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthRefreshTokenExpiredException:
>   MSIS9303: The OAuth refresh token received has expired.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthTokenProtocolHandler.ValidateRefreshToken(OAuthRefreshToken
>   refreshToken)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthTokenProtocolHandler.RedeemRefreshToken(OAuthRefreshTokenRequestContext
>   tokenContext)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the exact same issue for about a month now.  I have credential suppression enabled so it's not supposed to prompt.  Of course, once the OAUTH token expires,  I have to click "Manage Credentials" and it automatically sends my credentials and fixes the issue.  I've worked a little with Microsoft on this issue and they told me this 1021 event is expected behavior as all tokens will periodically expire(obviously).

Are your clients on Windows 8.1?  If so KB2976918 is supposed to fix it.  This will be released August 14th.  I'm still experiencing the error with Windows 7 Work Folders clients, which is unexpected.  I'll update as I find out more.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So far I can't seem to find any details yet on KB2976918, but I'll let you know if this fixes my problem on 8.1... And although it is "expected behavior" that the OAuth token times out, it makes Work Folder less usable in a real-world scenario: our not-so-very-tech-savvy users will not understand why they have to click on that link every X days and why it doesn't work like OneDrive/Dropbox/etc...

Comment: The KB is online: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2976918 I have installed it. I'll let you know if this solves the issue. Note that "Set-AdfsGlobalAuthenticationPolicy -WindowsIntegratedFallbackEnabled True" should be "Set-AdfsGlobalAuthenticationPolicy -WindowsIntegratedFallbackEnabled" (without the True at the end!)